# Conversion from string to date time in C#

Tags: c#

I have a table for different TimeZones in SQL server, i have one entry for USA (-5:00) in IT....I get the value of it in string as -5:00, but when i am trying to convert it using Convert.ToDateTime or DateTime.parse it is throwing exception, how to convert "-5:00"(string) to DateTime???

```
string meetingtotimezone = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == model.MeetingToId).TimeZone.TimeZone1; // here i have "-5:00" value as string

DateTime meetingtotimezonedate = DateTime.Parse(meetingtotimezone); // throwing exception

DateTime meetingtotimezonedate = Convert.ToDateTime(meetingtotimezone); // throwing exception
```

Comment: What value would you expect it to be?

Comment: When converting from `String` to `DateTime` it's always better to give the string format you have.

Comment: If you need specific timezones, please don't even start with `DateTime`, use `DateTimeOffset` or a specialized library instead.

Comment: I think you should use `DateTimeOffSet` or [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) to deal with date format from different timezones, since standard `DateTime` has no significant portion to determine timezone (it only knows `DateTimeKind.Local` or `DateTimeKind.Utc`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert your timezone value into a [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) using the [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Then you can calculate with that value as if it were a number:

```
string input = "-5:00";

TimeSpan difference = TimeSpan.Parse(input);

// this meeting would be at 14:00 
DateTime meetingTime = new DateTime(2018, 1, 20, 14, 0,0,0);

// time of the meeting in the other timezone
DateTime meetingtotimezonedate = meetingTime + difference;

Console.WriteLine(meetingtotimezonedate.ToShortTimeString());
```

Output:

> 09:00

Comment: If the meeting was at 14:00 in my timezone, then the output wouldn't be 09:00... my timezone is UTC+01:00 currently. Or in other words: you should better make the input meeting time explicit instead of commenting `in your timezone`